# Automatically generating items for a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which displays arrays from the arrays.xml in a list. The problem is, instead of reading it from xml, I want it to automatically create items from an int. For example if the int is 10, then it should create 10 list items- chapter 1, chapter 2, ... chapter 10.

```
 list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row_customizations, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray));
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            AudioBible.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });

    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String productName = adapter.getItem(position);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                String product = array[i];
                if (product.equals(productName)) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AudioBible.this, TTS.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("key", i);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should populate the list manually.

```
int count = x;

String[] array = new String[count];

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
   array[i] = ("Chapter " + (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: could not make it work. can you edit my code please?

Comment: there try it, i used `array` instead of an `arraylist`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);`

create array programatically and pass it into your adapter

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   array.add("Chapter " + i++);
}
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row_customizations, array);
```